# AS3 Embed dynamic audio file(s) / Use variables in embed

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

Making a piano/keyboard application and trying to figure out the best way to set this up and would love any suggestions

I plan on having a directory of sounds for each 'instrument' in my assets folder (piano1/C4.mp3,piano1/D4.mpg,...)

Is there a way to import/embed all of these as an array? Also is there a way I can pass a variable to this class to indicate which folder I want to import these from?

Something that would be ideal

```
var type = "piano2"; //passed from class being called by
foreach(notes as note){
     [Embed(source = 'assets/sounds/'+type +'/'+note+'.mp3')] private const C3:Class;
     public var c3:Sfx = new Sfx(C3);
}
```

Or would it be a better idea to have a class for each of these "types" that pulls all notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that using `[Embed()]`. Embed is a compile time attribute not a run time attribute. You *could*, on the other hand, package your mp3 resources with your deploy-able (whether that is a swf or a air application), and use a [`Sound.load()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29).

Something like:

```
public initialize():void {
    var type = "piano2"; //passed from class being called by
    foreach(notes as note){
         var url = 'assets/sounds/'+type +'/'+note+'.mp3';
         var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
         var sound:Sound = new Sound();
         sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, noteLoaded);
         sound.load(req);
    }
}

private noteLoaded(e:Event):void {
    // do something with the loaded sound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made myself a script to import graphical assets faster, you can do the same for your sounds.
Import every songs in a .fla named something like sounds.fla . You can then order them as you wish by creating folders. Once that done i have a jsfl script that parses everything i selected and then creates an empty class for importing and then it prints out something like this.

```
//      this is the name         this is the class referencing what i exported in flash
private ID_PIANO_SOUND_1:Sound = getClassByName(PIANO_SOUND_1);
private ID_PIANO_SOUND_2:Sound = getClassByName(PIANO_SOUND_2);
private ID_PIANO_SOUND_3:Sound = getClassByName(PIANO_SOUND_3);
private ID_GUITAR_SOUND_1:Sound = getClassByName(GUITAR_SOUND_1);
```

So i can just paste that and shove it into a static class inside flash. Your sounds.fla needs to be compiled as swc and embed into your project.

Good luck!